# how to identify the first, second and third element when the object names are the same in CodedUI tests

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am writing CodedUI tests for a web application. There are three text boxes with the same name and I would like to know how do we call these text boxes ? Please advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
  var control = new HtmlControl(parent)
  control.SearchProperties.Add([Control Type], [Control Name]);
  var specificControl = control.FindMatchingControls()[index]
```

In the above code, what it does is find the three controls you mentioned with the same name, and then index them in a collection.  By taking a piece of that collection with "[index]", you can isolate a single control.

This is what it looks like in practice in a WPF app:

```
    //Identify the cell and minimize button 2017
    WpfCell currentyearCell = new WpfCell(workWindow);
    currentyearCell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.Value, DateTime.Now.AddYears(0).ToString("yyyy"));
    currentyearCell = currentyearCell.FindMatchingControls()[0] as WpfCell;
```

Answer (score 0):

If 3 elements has same property and if you will provide a search properties
Control.searchproperties.add("","")
And you intend to select 2 element.Than by this approach it will automatically identify the first element.
Just go for next sibling search configuration.
So it will go the next element or we can use children element[pass the index]